# Not able to generate HTML report in ApacheJmeter-5.4.1 on mac

Tags: java, macos, jmeter

Not able to generate HTML report in ApacheJmeter-5.4.1 on mac.

```
Mac OS version : 12.0.1
Jmeter version : 5.4.1
Java version :
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Getting below error while generating report using jmeter -g /jtl/file/name/with/path -o /output/folder,

```
WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop
An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5
```

In one of the article I read that it is due to java compatibility issue, but I have tried with Java jdk1.8, jdk15.0, jdk 17.0 but no luck. Please help.

Comment: I had similar issue with JDK `java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS` and was. resolved with JDK 1.8.

Comment: tried the same i.e with jdk 1.8 but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I had installed jmeter `5.4.1` with [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jmeter). I was getting the same error running from the command line with many different openjdk versions (8, 11.0, 16.0, 17.0). I'm running these tests on an Ubuntu 18.04.6 machine.

I tried re-installing jmeter with homebrew, but I was still getting this error. I also read online that this usually has to do with java compatibility issues (hence why I tried so many different jdk versions).

Finally, I installed jmeter `5.4.1` [directly from apache](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), and it started working with jdk1.8.